# SQL Server 2005 UniqueIdentifier and C# Data Type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, uniqueidentifier

What is the best data type to choose in C# for representing a SQL Server UniqueIdentifier type?  I was going to use a GUID but I've seen people using varChars.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

System.Guid is what you need.

You can learn about CLR equivalents of SQL data types in this article:

[SQL Server Data Types and Their .NET Framework Equivalents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I use a uniqueidentifier sql data type I always map it to a Guid in C#.  I don't think I've ever seen it done differently.

Comment: +1.  People using varchars to represent GUIDs or strings to represent UNIQUEIDENTIFIER are using the *wrong type*.

Answer (score 4):

GUID is the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

GUID is the direct comparison.